# como identifico a quantidade que se repetiu e os nomes repetidos?

Tags: loop, portugol

Fazer um algoritmo em portugol que leia o nome de até 100 pessoas e informe a quantidade de nomes iguais a "jose da silva" e a quantidade de nomes iguais a "ana maria". O algoritmo não deve aceitar nomes vazios.

```
algoritmo semNome;
// Síntese
//  Objetivo: ler o nome de até 100 pessoas e informar a quantidade de nomes iguais
//  Entrada :nome
//  Saída   :nomes iguais
//Dados de entada
//joão
//joão
//luca
//Dados de saida
//joão
//1

principal
    // Declarações
    inteiro qtdNomes ;
    texto nome,nomeRepetido;


    // Instruções
    nomeRepetido="nome";
    qtdNomes=0;
    enquanto(qtdNomes<3)faca
        escreval("nome:");
        leia(nome);
        qtdNomes=qtdNomes+1;
    fimEnquanto


    se(comparaTexto(nome,nome)==0)entao
        nomeRepetido=nome;
    fimSe

    se (comparaTexto(nome,nomeRepetido)==0)entao
        escreval("nome:",nome);

    fimSe
fimPrincipal
```

Comment: Faltou o seu código, amigo. O StackOverFlow não distribui código, apenas corrigi ou revisa

Comment: a simm, vlw. É que sou novo aqui .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma dica para te ajudar: divida o problema em partes para facilitar tua implementação:

1. Você deve ler até **100** nomes válidos (não vazios)

   - Isto é um laço que se repetirá até atingir uma condição;
   - Se o nome não for vazio você incrementa o contador de nomes válidos em 1 e e
   - Se o contador chegar em 100 você sai do laço
2. Você deve ter um contador para cada um dos nomes que irá pesquisar a repetição:

   - Cada vez que um nome não vazio for lido
   - Se o nome é igual a "**José da Silva**", incremente em 1 o contador dele e
   - Se o nome for igual a "**Ana Maria**" você incrementa em 1 o contador dela.
3. Você deve escrever o número de repetições.

   - Isto só será executado depois que todos os **100** nomes foram lidos
   - Daí você escreve o valor do contador de nomes do "**José da Silva**" e
   - Escreve o valor do contador de nome da "**Ana Maria**".

Implemente cada parte na ordem e você verá a resolução ficou bem mais simples.